# In django How to query a model based on already existing queryset of same model

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I want to do following in django:

assuming I have model called `Account`

`accountset1 = Account.objects.filter(some query)`

`accountset2 = Account.objects.filter(some other query)`

`accounts = Account.objects.filter("account in either of accountset1  accountset2")`

how can I do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [`Q` object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) and make a query in one line.

```
from django.db.models import Q
accounts = Account.objects.filter(Q(some query) | Q(some other query))
```